# Pandas add Mean column header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to add column header for a mean column. Refer to below
Mean for each column in df :

```
    A   B   C
0   5   3   8
1   5   3   9
2   8   4   9

df.mean()

A    6.000000
B    3.333333
C    8.666667
dtype: float64
```

What I want to achieve is below output:

```
     Mean
A    6.000000
B    3.333333
C    8.666667
dtype: float64
```

So far I've tried `df.columns['Mean']` but does not work. I think it's something to do with the dtype float64 instead of standard dataframe object. Can anyone give a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [rename the series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) and use [`series.to_frame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

```
df.mean().rename('Mean').to_frame()
```

Or as suggested by @user3483203, `to_frame()` accepts a name parameter too:

```
df.mean().to_frame('Mean')
```

---

```
       Mean
A  6.000000
B  3.333333
C  8.666667
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thx!

Comment: `df.mean().to_frame('Mean')`

Comment: @user3483203 thanks :) that is cleaner.. added to the solution

Answer (score 1):

@anky answer is the way to go. This is just a different way to show the way using `agg` :)

```
df.agg(['mean']).T

Out[493]:
       mean
A  6.000000
B  3.333333
C  8.666667
```

Comment: very `*Mean*` :P

Comment: @anky: haha... I just feel bored, so I want to try something different :))